# Pureconfig Typesafe Config with sealed abstract case class

Tags: class, case, abstract, sealed, pureconfig

I am trying to incorporate Pureconfig in my use case for typesafe configurations. Been successful in mapping HOCON .conf to case class types. However, if I have to constrain my types with no side-effects on the object definition side (i.e., supress default apply() and copy()), I am using following definition approach for case class:

```
sealed abstract case class someConfig(name:String)

object someConfig{
    def apply(name:String):Option[someConfig]={
        if(Option(name).isDefined && name.nonEmpty){
            Some(new someConfig(name){})
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

To support Option[_] types, I am considering having an implicit ConfigReader. This approach seems to work, with a bit more for me to address config-keys to object mapping and instantiation.

Examples that I have searched upon so far doesn't seem to resonate this need. However, do see use of Option[_] on the object members. Tried to walk through the code samples in Pureconfig git repo.

Could someone suggest an approach where Option[T] could be supported, where T is a composite custom type? And I don't have to deal with member variable name to config key mapping, etc. i.e., avoid necessary boilerplate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've hidden the constructor for your class in order to channel validation through the `apply`, you'll have to manually construct a `ConfigReader`. I believe that's about as simple as putting this in your companion object:

```
implicit val configReader = 
  pureconfig.ConfigReader.fromNonEmptyStringOpt[someConfig](apply)
```

Alternatively, you could name the class implementing your abstract type in which case [PureConfig's automatic derivation for sealed families](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/overriding-behavior-for-sealed-families.html) would magically create the `ConfigReader` for you.

Comment: marking this as closed. Alternate approach (in-line to the above link on automatic derivation...) did work. That meets my need to suppress default apply() and copy(), besides being able to auto-magically map between config to desired ADT. For extensibility could also have a abstract class extend the trait, to be able to generalize the serialization requirement (override def toString()).

Comment: Further, settled with approach of having a `case class` with a copy(...) method that matches the only constructor that I needed to allow. This solved the issue of suppressing default apply() and copy() methods. As a refinement, I could define a macro that can be applied to ADT's to include a matching copy(...) method.  Scala version that I tried - 2.12.3